# block takes 2 arguments, but the Regexp matched 1 argument

Tags: ruby, capybara

What is the issue here? Trying to merge a previous author's code  (use of my) with the step definition down below.  I get the following error when the first step % is called in the first step definition.  Is this error saying the receiving step definition is expecting two arguments, the table and @name which is set elsewhere and I am only calling it with the table user_role value?
  # FAILS WITH: Your block takes 2 arguments, but the Regexp matched 1 argument.

```
Then I make my person a user with role of "Peak Admin" in Peak

When(/^I make my person a user with role of "([^"]*)" in Peak$/) do |role|
  step %{I make my person a user in Peak
   | user_role | role | }
end

Then(/^I make my person a user in Peak$/) do |table|
  step %{I make the person "#{@name}" a user in Peak
    | user_role | table.rows_hash[:user_role] |}
end

When(/I make the person "([^"]*)" a user in Peak$/) do |person,table|
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling steps that take data tables correctly inside your other steps - see the cucumber wiki - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-Step-Definitions#calling-steps-with-multiline-step-arguments

Following that your first step becomes something like

```
When(/^I make my person a user with role of "([^"]*)" in Peak$/) do |role|
  step "I make my person a user in Peak", table([
    [ "user_role", role]
  ])
end
```